# state is not accessible inside a function in React

Tags: reactjs

I have React functional component and trying to do drag and drop feature. I found an article doing that but it is using React Class component at [DragandDrop using React Class Component](https://tinloof.com/blog/how-to-make-and-test-your-own-react-drag-and-drop-list-with-0-dependencies/). So, I convert it to React Functional Component but having problem.I couldn't find the reason  why the state is not accessible inside the onDragOver function. Here is my code:

```
      function MenuCreatorCourse() {
          const [items, setItems] = useState([1, 2]);
        
          let draggedItem = null;
          function onDragStart(e, index) {
            draggedItem = items[index];
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
            e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", e.target.parentNode);
            e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target.parentNode, 20, 20);
            console.log("draggedItem @ DragStart", draggedItem);
          }
          function onDragOver(e, index) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("@onDragOver", index, items);
        }...
    ...
     <ul onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault}>
                {items.map((item, idx) => (
                  <li
                    className={classes.courseinput}
                    key={item}
                    onDragOver={(e) => onDragOver(e, idx)}
                  >
                    <div
                      className="drag"
                      draggable
                      onDragStart={(e) => onDragStart(e, idx)}
                      onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
                    >
                    
                      {console.log("item", item)}
                      <DragAndDropIcon />
                    </div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div className="form-control">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        id="description"
                        placeholder="Description"
                     
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <RemoveIcon />
                    </div>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
  );
}

export default MenuCreatorCourse;
```

My issue is that the log at "@onDragOver" return the following result as in screenshot. It seems the 'items' state is not accessible inside the onDragOver function, but is accessible inside the onDragStart function
[Screenshot of the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ll9C.png)

**Update:**

```
const onDragOver = (e, index) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    const draggedOverItem = items[index];
    console.log("@onDragOver", index, items);
    console.log("draggedOverItem", draggedOverItem);
    // if the item is dragged over itself, ignore
    if (draggedItem === draggedOverItem) {
      return;
    }

    // filter out the currently dragged item
    let newitems = items.filter((item) => item !== draggedItem);

    // add the dragged item after the dragged over item
    items.splice(index, 0, draggedItem);

    setItems(items);
    console.log("draggedItem @ DragOver", draggedItem);
  };
```

Comment: as long as handler is inside the Component function, it should work. Try restarting the dev server.

Comment: Hi Daniel, i restarted the dev and still having same issue, cannot access the items state

Comment: It seems the items value is there. It was the code below it that causing the issue. Pplease see my update code that include the codes below the ' console.log("@onDragOver", index, items);' .Now I suspect the issue is coming from the let newitems...

Comment: you cant manipulate items variable since its immutable by default. the only way to make changes is by setItems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([1, 2]);
```

items immutable. you can't manipulate that variable. You will have to make a new variable by spreading contents of items and do the manipulation on that, before updating values using setItems.

### invalid

```
items.splice(index, 0, draggedItem);
```

### valid

```
let newvaritem = [...items]
newvaritem .splice(index, 0, draggedItem);
```

Comment: i have added the line which is invalid and how to make it valid. check it out. and pass the newvaritem to setItems()

Comment: OK, let me try it. but where can I find the  "I have added the line and how to make it valid "?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that give me a light to solve my question. That we need to copy array to a new array then mutate the new array, and finally use setter to set the array to the items state.